# how to uninstall "./tweaks.sh" firefox gtk customization

Tags: firefox

I wanted to customize Ubuntu with WhiteSur theme. Found this [githup repo](https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme) that lets me do that. I customized firefox with their `./tweaks.sh -f` command. Now I want to remove that customization (kind of looks bloated). How do i do that?

Comment: see the help of the script; there is a remove option: https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme/blob/master/tweaks.sh

Answer (score 1):

Close Firefox Browser, Then
Delete the code inside the file `~/.mozilla/firefox/firefox-themes/userChrome.css`

Restart Firefox.

You will see the default look of Firefox